# SQL joomla search: multiple words, second dependant on first

Tags: sql, joomla

Searchstring is: "Police Denver".

I need the result to be just that, Police in Denver. Now i get every Police and everything in Denver.

This is what i have, this is the part that specifies if the search should be EXACT or ANY. But it's not working as I whant it to. "Police Denver" results in nothing and Police Denver results in Police in Chicago, Firemen in Denver and so on...

(The code is from k2 joomla extension, open source)

```
$sql .= " AND MATCH(i.title, i.introtext, i.`fulltext`,i.image_caption,i.image_credits,i.video_caption,i.video_credits,i.extra_fields_search,i.metadesc,i.metakey) ";
        if ($type == 'exact')
        {
            $text = JString::trim($search, '"');
            $escaped = K2_JVERSION == '15' ? $db->getEscaped($text, true) : $db->escape($text, true);
            $text = $db->Quote('"'.$db->getEscaped($text, true).'"', false);
        }
        else //this is search for any of the words
        {
            $search = JString::str_ireplace('*', '', $search);
            $words = explode(' ', $search);
            for ($i = 0; $i < count($words); $i++)
            {
                $words[$i] .= '*';
            }
            $search = implode(' ', $words);
            $escaped = K2_JVERSION == '15' ? $db->getEscaped($search, true) : $db->escape($search, true);
            $text = $db->Quote($escaped, false);
        }
        $sql .= " AGAINST ({$text} IN BOOLEAN MODE)";

    }

    return $sql;
```

Comment: I would use smart search if possible.

Comment: Never thought of that, Elin. Guess I need a plugin for Joomla to search K2 items. I will take a look at this. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Answer this myself as I found a way:

I just added

```
$words[$i] = "+".$words[$i];
```

in the for() loop and it works.